# How to find acoustical output of a horn?

Tags: energy, acoustics

If I had a horn or cone that could be written as a function $f(x)$ rotated around the x-axis, how would I calculate the output, knowing the input (intensity, frequency, everything)? I want a way to qualitatively calculate the resulting sound intensity and frequency (if there is a change)

[image]

Comment: Maybe a diagram would help?

Comment: [This may be of some interest](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178023/25301), but I don't think it answers the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this would be to assume that all of the sound produces at the ``throat area'' stays trapped within the horn. Then, there is a spreading of the signal as it travels down the tube. Then, the amount of flux leaving the end should be equal to the flux at the throat. 
Suppose the initial intensity is $ I_{0} $,  and throat area is $ A $. The initial flux is $ I_{0} A $. At the point x, the flux is $ I(x) A e^{4 \pi x / \lambda} = I_{0} A $.
Therefore, the intensity should satisfy $ I(x) = I_{0} e^{-4 \pi x / \lambda} $.

Calculating a frequency shift would be challenging, so I'm not sure about that.

Also, if this is supposed to model a megaphone, it's a pretty different model you want, because the point of the megaphone is to couple to your vocal chords and radiate the sound around the surface of the phone. In this case, I'm assuming the sound is produced in the air and the surface is reflecting the sound, trapping it in the channel.